# How to join data by special order to svg text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

my data is like

```
const data = [
  { name: 'Jane', age: 90 },
  { name: 'Paul', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Jerry', age: 32 },
  { name: 'Mary', age: 75 },
];
```

my svg is like

```
<svg>
  <g data-name='Jerry'><text>Jerry</text> <text>age</text> <text class='age'>0</text></g>  
  <g data-name='Paul'><text>Paul</text> <text>age</text> <text class='age'>0</text></g>
  <g data-name='Mary'><text>Mary</text> <text>age</text> <text class='age'>0</text></g>
  <g data-name='Jane'><text>Jane</text> <text>age</text> <text class='age'>0</text></g>
</svg>
```

As you can see above, data and svg is not sorted by name.

I want to keep this order `Jerry → Paul → Mary → Jane`. But every time I tried to join the data using d3, it joined with data's order (`jane → paul → jerry → mary`)

I have no clue how to join data in svg's order. :(

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll('.age').data(data).text(function(d){return d.age})
```

Is there any way to solve this? any clues?

or maybe this is not the correct or propery way using d3? :(

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a key function when binding the data. However, you have two complicating factors here:

1. Since you already have elements to which you want to bind the data, you have to check for the unique property in the data **and** the element's `data` property, because the element has no bound data when the function first runs.
2. The `data` property is in the parent, not in the element itself, therefore you need to use `parentNode`:

   ```
   .data(data, function(d) {
       return d ? d.name : this.parentNode.dataset.name
   })
   ```

Here's your code with the key function:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 90
  },
  {
    name: 'Paul',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 75
  },
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll('.age')
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d ? d.name : this.parentNode.dataset.name
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.age
  })
```

```html
<svg>
  <g transform='translate(30,20)' data-name='Jerry'><text>Jerry</text> <text x="50">age</text> <text class='age' x="80">0</text></g>  
  <g transform='translate(30,40)' data-name='Paul'><text>Paul</text> <text x="50">age</text> <text class='age' x="80">0</text></g>
  <g transform='translate(30,60)' data-name='Mary'><text>Mary</text> <text x="50">age</text> <text class='age' x="80">0</text></g>
  <g transform='translate(30,80)' data-name='Jane'><text>Jane</text> <text x="50">age</text> <text class='age' x="80">0</text></g>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```